# Counter Macro VBA Powerpoint

Tags: vba, counter, increment, powerpoint

I want to make a macro in powerpoint that increments by 1 the number when I click on the button, I have the following macro that increments the counter between a delay of seconds but I want to increment the counter when I click, how can I change it?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Offset = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight + 10
CountNo = 1
' ADJUST THIS waitTime NUMBER WITH SECONDS DELAY BETWEEN COUNTER INCREMENTS
waitTime = 0.5
' ADJUST THIS maxCount NUMBER WITH MAXIMUM NUMBER COUNTER SHOULD REACH
maxCount = 5000

Do Until CountNo = maxCount + 1
  ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CountNo
  ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").Top = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").Top + Offset
  DoEvents
  ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").Top = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").Top - Offset

  x = Timer
  While Timer - x < waitTime
    DoEvents
  Wend

  CountNo = CountNo + 1

  If SlideShowWindows.Count = 0 Then
    ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = 1
    ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").Top = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").Top + Offset
    DoEvents
    ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").Top = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").Top - Offset
    Exit Do
  End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you asked the wrong question, but to give you an example:

This reads the `CountNo` from a shape, increases the counter by one and writes it back to the shape everytime you click that button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim CountNo As Long
    CountNo = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").TextFrame.TextRange.Text 
      'read the count no from the shape counter

    CountNo = CountNo + 1 'increase the count no by 1

    ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CountNo
      'write the count no back to the shape counter
End Sub
```

This code expects that in `ActivePresentation.SlideMaster` there is a shape `.Shapes("Counter")` that contains a number in its `.TextFrame.TextRange.Text`.